# Object.keys results in an inconsistent/different ordering compared to the keys in Firebase Data

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

New to firebase. See the pick below, firebase returns these records in random order everytime. Is this a known behavior? I have googled this so much and every post that comes up is about randomizing the order.
Also, you might find that timestamp key to be weird, that's a different debate but if you have a suggestion how I can structure this data better, please advise.

Thank you!

[image]

[image]

```
export const getMonthlyData = async (month, user) => {
  const performanceRef = firestore.doc(`performance/${user.id}`);
  const doc = await performanceRef.get();

    if(doc.exists) {
      const docArray = Object.keys(doc.data());
      console.log("Docs>>>>>>", docArray);
   }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "these records"? Please edit the question to show the code you're using, and give an example of results that you're observing that are different than what you expect.  You should note the the names of fields are all strings, and documents are essentially hash maps of those fields.

Comment: @DougStevenson embarrassed that I did not catch it, it's actually Object.keys that changes the data. I added the code above and an image.

Comment: Have you tried .values() or .entries() to see if it fixes this then?

Comment: (value/entries has the same ordering as keys.)

Comment: or maybe create your own key:value pair from the data with .reduce()

Comment: Doesn't `Object.keys` return the properties in the order they were added to the object?

Comment: The OP originally was having an issue with the default "keys" that were being assigned is my presupposition for my statements.

Comment: Why are your keys localised date strings?

Comment: @fubar Yes^, since ES2015 - presumably the insertion order matches that from the backend. (^This only strictly applies to string and symbol keys.)

Comment: @Phil I'm no backend developer but probably can come up with a better structure in a SQL database. I'm just trying to serve some data for my react app that I am practicing on. If you have a better suggestion to structure that data, please advise.

Comment: @fubar ok, so then the order should not change right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firestore SDK gives no guarantee to the order of iteration of the properties of objects.  When you call `Object.keys()`, you're going to get an array of strings with an order that is not predetermined.  If you require for them to have an order, you should sort them yourself before processing them.

Comment: @user2864740 The SDK doesn't give any documented guarantee, so one should not assume as much.

Comment: @user2864740 In case you didn't notice, I edited the answer.